# Are there any rules/guidelines for drinking water?

Tags: scripture, food

We all are aware of different types of food i.e satvik, rajas and tamas also why  some type of food should not be eaten by the yogis or how many times a yogi must eat during the day but my question is do we have any rules for drinking water? For instance how many times or how much water should a yogi drink?

Reason for asking is because now we usually get treated water everywhere that has chlorine and chloramine which does have impact on our pineal gland and for yogis pineal gland activation is really important.

Ideally I would like to see scriptural references in the answers, if possible.

Comment: Drink water when you feel thirsty and amount your belly fits and not because some scripture says the times and amount it says.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Going by ur logic we should also eat then whenever we feel hungry and eat as much as our stomach can take. But according to scriptures that's not the right way. There are definite rules when to eat and how much to eat. So, there's no harm in asking the same for water intake.

Comment: @Rickross That is the way one should eat. You should not eat just a book says even when your belly is full and not feeling hungry at all.It leads to ill health. This is not a good question.If scripture contradicts what is false, that should be rejected. God has given us our own thinking. We have to use it and not blindly follow because a book is saying something. And I didn't say "as much as as you can eat".. I said what fits in your belly. Re read my comment.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma when we have rules for eating, sleeping + so many other things then why can't we have for drinking water? As for your comment "eat as much as fits your belly" is pretty absurd indeed coz that is what's happening now a days and leading to obesity!

Comment: There are many rules in smritis and scriptures even how many times and when one should pee and poop. Do we really follow only by that rule and don't go at other times? We have to use our common sense in such cases and there's a body clock which gives signals. We should go by that and not blindly follow something because a book says how and when.In  MB says " that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the test of reason" and "Even one thousand scriptural statements cannot transform a jar into a piece of cloth".by Vachaspati mishra. So, intellect comes first in this matters.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, it is a combination of both. we should eat WHEN we are hungry (listen to stomach), but we should not eat WHENEVER we are hungry (listen to shastras). shastras mostly put restrictions, they don't deal much with permissions, because they know we will automatically want to eat when hungry, drink when thirsty, sleep when tired. we do not need shastras to tell us to eat food (eat when hungry), but we need shastras to tell us when NOT to eat food (don't eat before bathing).

Comment: @Just_Do_It Are you by any chance asking this question as a health advice? That is off-topic. This site is not for getting health advises. Try [health] instead. This could be misleading. You should get a professional advice on these matters.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma OP is asking "As per scriptures what are the rules for water consumption  .." so scripture is a valid tag..

Comment: @Rickross Answers from scriptures is only an option. He said "if possible". We can't tag it because 1 answer is from scripture.Other sourcesare also valid. Scripture is a tag when we ask _about_ scriptures. This is not asking about scriptures. It's asking abot food. We don't tag acharya or blog or website if we need as per acharya's words or websites. Do we? Tags indicate the content of the question and not the source of an answer. A sentence in the body is enough for that.

Comment: He is clearly asking what the scriptures say about it. He is not asking what me or u think about it. So scripture is a valid tag. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Rickross "Ideally I would like to see scriptural references in the answers, _if possible_." Do you see it? Not only scriptures like puranas, smritis or Vedas, there are many other valid references which can be used to answer this question. Everyone knows he is asking for personal opinions. Don't tag it based on one answer.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Not asking this question as a health advice but from yogic practices point of view and not asking for personal opinions as that would be of no help to me.

Comment: Rainwater is said to be the most clean water I believe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know about an interesting Mantra from the Vedas which is probably giving an indication to the amount of water we should intake.

> samAni prapA saha vonnabhAgah ||
>
> May your water drinking equal your food intake (anna).
>
> *Atharva Veda 3.30.3*

Apart from that it is also not recommended that we use frothy water (i.e with bubbles) while we are sipping water for Achamana. So, water which has bubbles in it (like the soft drinks have) is obviously considered as impure and drinking such water must also not be recommended.

> Manu Smriti 2.61. He who knows the sacred law and seeks purity shall
>   always perform the rite of sipping with water neither hot **nor
>   frothy**, with the (prescribed) tirtha, in a lonely place, and turning
>   to the east or to the north.

I think it's believed that water also accepted to share Indra's guilt of slaying Vritta (who was a Brahmin) and that sin/impurity stays in the bubbles of the water.

These are the only rules of water consumption, in general, that I'm aware of.

For the Yogis, in particular, the Hatha Yoga Pradipika says that the Yogi should consume only pure water.

> Varjayeddurjanaprāntam vahnistrīpathisevanam |
>  Prātahsnānopavāsādi
>   kāyakleśavidhim tathā ||
>
> Wheat, rice, barley, shâstik (a kind of rice), good corns, milk, ghee,
>   sugar, butter, sugarcandy, honey, dried ginger, Parwal (a vegetable)
>   the five vegetables, moong, pure water; these are very beneficial to
>   those who practise Yoga

Comment: are there any rules as to when to drink it after having food? From what I know we should not drink it immediately after eating food as it will affect 'agni' that helps in food digestion.

Comment: Yes that is what my mom says too. But I can not remember reading anything like that so far. So nothing to cite. @Just_Do_It

Comment: @Just_Do_It अजीर्णे भेषजं वारि, जीर्णे वारि बलप्रदम् ।
भोजने चामृतं वारि, **भोजनान्ते विषप्रदम्** ॥...i remember studying this in Sansakrit subject in school not sure abt its actual source...